# Dojo.hitch() scope question

Tags: javascript, dojo, scope

Why is it that when I use the dojo.hitch function and try to reference the "this" operator inside it, that it gives me reference to the wrong object?

```
console.debug(dijit.byId("widgetName"));  //works as expected and prints out the window object

dojo.hitch(dijit.byId("widgetName"), tester())();   //this should be executing the tester function in the scope of the widget object

function tester() {
    console.debug(this);    //prints out the Javascript Window object instead of the widget object!!!!
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That should not happen, don't believe that what you have posted is the same as what you are attempting in your application. Any scnreenshots to back it up?

Comment: Are you sure it returns correctly if you put `console.log(dijit.byId("widgetName"))` just before the `hitch`? Does it return `null` by any chance? In that case, `this` refers to `window`.

Comment: @Layke I know it shouldn't happen, hence my question. Been scratching my head over it for sometime. This is a copy/paste code exactly from my app. I don't know what you want to see in the screenshot?!

Comment: @pimvdb, I tried that and it prints out the widget just fine. I really don't understand this and it is driving me insane...

Comment: @Layke I modified the question slightly because I changed my code since so I can debug it easier but it's basically the same result. Any ideas what i can try next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on what you have just shown, I can now safely provide an answer explaining what is wrong.

When you do a `dojo.hitch()` you should not call the function inside of it, but instead call the result of the function. That is, you need to provide `dojo.hitch` with a reference to the function to hitch, not the result of invoking that function.

In your example, you are calling `tester()` (which invokes the function `tester`) inside of the `dojo.hitch()`, which calls the `tester` once. Even though you have `dojo.hitch()();` because `tester()` does not return a function handler (but the result of `tester`, in this case `undefined`), the `hitch()();` does nothing. That might have been confusing so I will show you with an example.

Don't do this:

> dojo.hitch( context, handler() )();

Instead do this:

> dojo.hitch( context, handler )();

So to make what you have very readable you would do this:

```
widget = dijit.byId("widgetName"); 
tester = function() {
    console.log(this);
}

handle = dojo.hitch(widget, tester);
handle();
```

Your mistake was trying to call the function from within the `dojo.hitch()`. This mistake also was not present in your original question.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to help. But what if I want to pass in any parameters to tester? i.e. dojo.hitch(widget, tester('myparam'));

Comment: dojo.hitch() has a fourth parameter I believe which accepts parameters. Either a fourth or a third. I can't remember. Check out the dojo docs which have how to pass parameters through a dojo.hitch.